# Search by CAS Registry name to obtain trackable accession: ie InChI?

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

I'm updating a database and trying to move from CAS Registry names to InChIKeys. I have about ~800 compounds to track. Is there a way to do this mappings programatically? I'm looking for a web service or API that already has this implemented, does something like it exist?

Comment: [It might help](http://depth-first.com/articles/2010/11/01/chemcell-easily-convert-names-and-cas-numbers-to-chemical-structures-in-excel/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Chemical Identifier Resolver](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure) can convert several identifiers and has an API so you can convert with a script.

A Python example for CAS to InChIKey:

```python
from urllib.request import urlopen

def CIRconvert(cas):
    try:
        url = 'http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/' + cas + '/stdinchikey'
        ans = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
        return ans
    except:
        return cas

casno = ['50-78-2', '69-72-7', '95-1E-6', '108-24-7', '31710-30-2']

for casid in casno:
    print(CIRconvert(casid))
```

Output:

```
InChIKey=BSYNRYMUTXBXSQ-UHFFFAOYSA-N
InChIKey=YGSDEFSMJLZEOE-UHFFFAOYSA-N
95-1E-6
InChIKey=WFDIJRYMOXRFFG-UHFFFAOYSA-N
InChIKey=CIPFDHFTBYJKQB-UHFFFAOYSA-N
```

Comment: note that your code is syntactically wrong

Comment: @mykhal Just tested - code and service works.

Comment: It really works, sorry for the inconvenience. But I have edited the "buggy code".

Comment: @mykhal For future reference: [code prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/260760)

Answer (score 3):

Chemical Identifier Resolver has a python API also: https://cirpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

```
import cirpy
print(cirpy.resolve('107-13-1', 'stdinchikey'))
```

Output

```
InChIKey=NLHHRLWOUZZQLW-UHFFFAOYSA-N
```