# Chemical compound scaffolds name

Tags: nomenclature, molecules

in RDKit, there is this nice [function](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.Scaffolds.MurckoScaffold.html) to decompose a chemical compound into its scaffolds.

Is there a way to automatically name the scaffolds?

I usually search names in PubChem but this may not be practical for a large dataaset.

Comment: Look at your answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98055/search-by-cas-registry-name-to-obtain-trackable-accession-ie-inchi/134993#134993 and use `iupac_name` as output.

Comment: @rapelpy thank you `import cirpy  
print(cirpy.resolve('O=C1c2ccccc2OCC1Cc1ccccc1', 'iupac_name'))  
print(cirpy.resolve('O=C1c2ccccc2OCC1Cc1ccccc1', 'names'))`  seem to work